# GIF to HTML5 video conversion

Tags: php, beginner

I'm still at a very beginner level and I'm constantly working on small things to try and develop my skills. I'm hoping someone could just give me a quick review if there's anything obviously horrible about the code from my main PHP class. It's not feature-complete, but I'm hoping at this point I should be able to get a good review that will help me prevent future mistakes.

My [full source can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/wshrews/gif2html5/src) and a live demo is temporarily working here:

```
http://162.243.44.206/gif2html5/
```

---

```
class Gif2Html5
{
    private $uploadDir;
    private $fileSizeLimitBytes;
    private $isWindows;

    function __construct($uploadDir, $fileSizeLimitMB = 4)
    {
        $this->uploadDir = $uploadDir;
        $this->fileSizeLimitBytes = $fileSizeLimitMB * 1048576;
        $this->isWindows = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN' ? true : false;
    }


    public function create()
    {
        if (!isset($_FILES['uploadImage'])) {
            echo "Please select the file you want to upload.";
            return;
        }

        if (filesize($_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name']) > $this->fileSizeLimitBytes) {
            echo "The file you uploaded exceeds the size limit of " . $this->fileSizeLimitBytes / 1048576 . "MB";
            return;
        }

        if ($_FILES['uploadImage']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $deleteKey = $this->generateRandomString(15);

            do {
                $randomDir = $this->generateRandomString(5);
            } while (file_exists($this->uploadDir . $randomDir));

            $newDir = $this->uploadDir . $randomDir . '/';
            mkdir($newDir, 0777, true);

            $uploadFile = $newDir . $randomDir . '.gif';

            if (!imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name'])) {
                echo "The uploaded image is not a valid .gif file.";
                return;
            }

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadImage']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) {
                echo "There was a problem moving the file to the upload directory.";
                return;
            }

            if (!$fp = fopen($newDir . $deleteKey . '.txt', 'wb')) {
                echo "There was a problem generating the delete key. Please try again later.";
                return;
            } else {
                fclose($fp);
            }

            if ($this->isWindows) {
                $exif = 'libraries/exif/WIN/exiftool.exe -v ';
                $h264 = 'libraries/ffmpeg/WIN/bin/ffmpeg.exe -r ';
                $webm = 'libraries/ffmpeg/WIN/bin/ffmpeg.exe -r ';
            } else {
                $exif = 'libraries/exif/LINUX/exiftool -v ';
                $h264 = 'libraries/ffmpeg/LINUX/ffmpeg -r ';
                $webm = 'libraries/ffmpeg/LINUX/ffmpeg -r ';
            }

            /*
             * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
             * Use exiftool to determine gif framecount and duration and calculate FPS.
             * http://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/
             * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
             */
            $exif .= $uploadFile;
            $c1 = $this->isWindows ? str_replace("/", "\\", $exif) : $exif;
            exec($c1, $out, $return);
            try {
                $x = explode(" = ", $out[sizeof($out) - 1]);
                $y = explode(" = ", $out[sizeof($out) - 2]);

                if(strtoupper(substr($x[0], 2, 11)) === "FRAMECOUNT"){
                    $fps = 10;
                } else if(strtoupper(substr($y[0], 2, 10)) === "FRAMECOUNT") {
                    $fps = $y[1] / $x[1];
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Potentially non-animated .gif file.');
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "There was a problem converting the uploaded .gif file.";
                return;
            }

            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadFile);
            if ($width % 2 != 0) {
                --$width;
            }
            if ($height % 2 != 0) {
                --$height;
            }

            /*
             * -----------------------------------------------
             * Use ffmpeg to convert the gif to webm and h264.
             * http://www.ffmpeg.org/
             * http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/
             * http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
             * -----------------------------------------------
             */
            $h264 .= $fps . ' -i ' . $uploadFile . ' -y -strict experimental -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 160k -vcodec libx264 -s ' . $width . 'x' . $height . ' -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 30 -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -b 1200k -f mp4 -threads 0 ' . $newDir . $randomDir . '.mp4';
            $webm .= $fps . ' -i ' . $uploadFile . ' -c:v libvpx -b 2000k ' . $newDir . $randomDir . '.webm';
            $c2 = $this->isWindows ? str_replace("/", "\\", $h264) : $h264;
            $c3 = $this->isWindows ? str_replace("/", "\\", $webm) : $webm;
            exec($c2);
            exec($c3);

            echo "./image/" . $randomDir . '/' . $deleteKey;
            return;
        }

        switch ($_FILES['uploadImage']['error']) {
            case 2:
                echo "The file you uploaded exceeds the size limit of " . $this->fileSizeLimitBytes / 1048576 . "MB";
                break;
            case 3:
                echo "The file upload failed part way - please try again.";
                break;
            case 4:
                echo "No file was uploaded. Please select a file and try again.";
                break;
            default:
                echo "An error occurred while uploading the file.";
                break;
        }

        return;
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        $requestedDir = $this->uploadDir . $id;
        $fileNoExt = $requestedDir . '/' . $id;
        $data['id'] = $id;
        if (@file_exists($requestedDir)) {
            $data['gif'] = @file_exists($fileNoExt . '.gif') ? true : false;
            $data['h264'] = @file_exists($fileNoExt . '.mp4') ? true : false;
            $data['webm'] = @file_exists($fileNoExt . '.webm') ? true : false;
            return $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function delete($id, $key)
    {
        $requestedDelete = $this->uploadDir . $id . '/' . $key . '.txt';
        if (@file_exists($requestedDelete)) {
            if($this->isWindows){
                $cmd = "RMDIR /s /q " . str_replace("/", "\\", $this->uploadDir . $id);
                exec ($cmd);
            } else {
                system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($this->uploadDir . $id));
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function generateRandomString($stringLength)
    {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $randomString = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $stringLength; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }

        return $randomString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `$this->isWindows = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN' ? true : false;` : Your check already evaluates to true. Essentially this reads as `if (true) then true else false`. It could be shorted to `$this->isWindows = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3))`.
- Your class has too many responsibilities: input validation, analyzing the gif, converting the gif, retrieving information for existing files as well as deleting files. I'd split this up into three classes: a service class for orchestrating the conversation, a file management class for retrieving information about existing files, deleting or creating them, and a converter class responsible for converting an existing and gif. This class should only check for constraints required by the conversation, not stuff like file-size and so on.  (Single Responsibility Principle)
- It's probably a good idea to have two classes for converation: one for linux and one for windows. Of course they should generalize common behavior in an abstract parent class. A nice side-effect would be to be able to add other conversion methods (or OS) easily without modifying the code (open/close principle).
- You are depending and modifying the global application state. The reusability of this class(es) is limited to a very specific use-case as the file needs to be in `$_FILES` and the information is `echo`d. I could not resuse this class somewhere else (e.g. for converting gifs in my command line tool).
- I suppose the `generateRandomString` method is a helper-method. It probably should be private.
- The gag-operator (`@`) is highly discouraged. Fix the problem instead of hiding it.
- Validate your keys and ids. A possible attack vector would be directory traversal: `->delete('../../../../../etc/', '');` or a like.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still at the stage where I find it difficult how to break up an application. My only question from your points is how do I avoid using $_FILES?

Comment: @SIL40: You can't $_FILES at all costs. Yet you could the caller decide to use $_FILES instead of the callee. This way your class doesn't know how the file got at the given location (be it by $_FILES or by already existing file) nor does it know the names of the form elements. And this class really doesn't need to know. In the MVC-Pattern this would be the job of the controller (with this class being your model or service).